# How to force geth to sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

Geth is refusing to sync the last 100 blocks on the ropsten testnet, is there a way to force geth to continue syncing from the console?

Comment: You will have to wait, it appears to be stuck but it is processing new 'states'.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run in the geth console

```
admin.peers.length
```

And

```
net.peerCount
```

To check if you are connected to any nodes?

Also you can check if you are currently synching to the network

```
eth.syncing
```

You can find out the current block number with

```
eth.getBlockNumber(console.log)
```

To make sure you are connecting to a ropsten node you can try adding the [bootstrap node](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/2b4c7e9b37958984525ba63f2ec637662b384090/params/bootnodes.go#L35) directly

```
admin.addPeer("enode://158f8aab45f6d19c6cbf4a089c2670541a8da11978a2f90dbf6a502a4a3bab80d288afdbeb7ec0ef6d92de563767f3b1ea9e8e334ca711e9f8e2df5a0385e8e6@13.75.154.138:30303")
```

Comment: I am connected to 2 other nodes according to those commands

Comment: I've added a few more checks to do

Comment: `eth.syncing` returns the currentBlock, highestBlock etc.. which are off by about ~60 blocks but it seems the currentBlock is not updating while the highestBlock is.

`eth.getBlockNumber(console.log)` returns `null 0 \n undefined`. 

Adding the boostrap node returned `true` but `admin.peers.length` and `net.peerCount` still return 2.